# Is it possible to insert string with variable inside include tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

In admin panel I can choose which template will be use to display content. Instead of multiple lines with if/elif statement I came to the conclusion that I can use for loop. However the problem is I don't know how to put variable inside string. Is it even possible?

I tried this ways:

```
{% include 'templates/template_'+ key + '.html' %}

{% include 'templates/template_{key}.html' %}

{% include f'templates/template_{key}.html' %}
```

but without success.

**models.py**

```py
class Homepage(models.Model):

    choice_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

    TEMPLATE_TYPE = [
        (choice_dict['one'], 'template-one'),
        (choice_dict['two'], 'template-two'),
        (choice_dict['three'], 'template-three'),
        (choice_dict['four'], 'template-four'),
        (choice_dict['five'], 'template-five'),
    ]

    template = models.IntegerField('Optional', choices=TEMPLATE_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    homepage = Homepage.objects.first()
    context = {
        'homepage': homepage,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```py
 {% if homepage.template %}

        {% for key, value in homepage.choice_dict.items %}
            {% if homepage.template == value %} {% include 'templates/template_'+ key + '.html' %}{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
```

Comment: create template name in views.py, send it to template and use this. {% include variable_name %}. it will work. I do it often for {% extends variable_name %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the add filter to do this

```py
    {% for key, value in homepage.choice_dict.items %}
        {% if homepage.template == value %} {% include 'templates/template_'|add:key|add:'.html' %}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
template_name = 'templates/template_'+ key + '.html'
 context = {
        'homepage': homepage,
        'template_name ': template_name ,
  }
```

in template

```
 {% if homepage.template %}

        {% for key, value in homepage.choice_dict.items %}
            {% if homepage.template == value %} {% include template_name %}{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
 {% else %}
```

Comment: Hmm..I tried this but in views.py  'key' is not defined.